# AWS S3 V3 Error trying to get list of objects inside a bucket. SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I have Reactjs project created using create-react-app and a aws s3 bucket in witch I've saved some images that I want to display on my website.

I have created a aws.js where I configure and make the call like this

```
import { S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { ListObjectsV2Command } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

const REGION  = 'eu-central-1'

const credentials = {
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    privateKeyId: privateKeyId,
}

const config = {
    region: REGION,
    credentials: credentials,
}

const bucketName = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
}

const s3Client = new S3Client(config);

export const run = async () => {
    try{
        const command = new ListObjectsV2Command(bucketName);
        const data = await s3Client.send(command);
        console.log("SUCCESS\n", data);
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log("ERROR\n", err);
    }
}
```

I have also created a .env filder where I saved the keys with and without REACT_APP prefix but the result is the same. Invalidating the credentials.

For credentials I've checked and rechecked 10 times and I also created a new user and use those keys but nothing. I also configured CORS to allow access from my localhost.

What I'm doing wrong? And is there a complete documentation from A-Z on what to use AWS services? Including v3, api doc, credentials set up and everything.

P.S. It's my first time using AWS so some docs would be much apreciated. Thanks in advance

UPDATE---
I tried to use aws javascript sdk v2 and now it works. Here is the code that I used to list objects inside a bucket

But it works only when I used AWS.config.update if I passed the configuration to the bucket it still thrown an error

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    region: region,
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey
});

let s3 = new AWS.S3()

export const testFnc = () =>{
    s3.listObjects({
        Bucket: 'artgalleryszili.digital'
    }, (res, err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
}
```